# How to use Windows User Certificate (S/MIME) to sign data

Tags: certificates

I am working on an internal ERP for my company. The portal is written in PHP and the current purchasing process is the following:

- Create a new order on the ERP portal
- Print the order (PDF)
- Ask for signature (manual ones)
- Scan the order
- Attach the scanned file to the digital order

Instead of this cumbersome process, I would like to use the employees certificates (Installed for each user) to generate a digital signature directly on the web portal. Of course, the private key must remain safely stored by Windows. This new process is much simpler, and more secure than a scanned document

- Create a new order on the ERP portal
- Concerned managers receive a signature request
- They approve the request (this is the tricky part)

Theoretically I just need to do this computation:

```
 $i = $order->id
 $a = $order->id + $order->integrityHash() 
 $b = sign($a, $private_key) // Done on the client side
 $order->signature = $b
 $order->save()
```

My main issue is how can I securely execute:

```
 $b = sign($a, $private_key)
```

With a user certificate stored in Windows 10  under `Certificates - Current User - Personal - Certificates` to sign JavaScript data in my Chrome browser.

I am thinking of these possible solutions:

1. Use an existing solution
2. Write a Chrome plugin

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280948/2612235)

In C# you will need to use the Windows Store:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
            {
                string desc = cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true);
                if (desc.Contains("WISeKey"))
                {
                    RSA pk = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();                    
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello World ... !");
                    byte[] signature = pk.SignData(buffer, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(signature));                  

                    break;
                }                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```